# How to store a user input permanently in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a high school project to making a fake model of ATM in python how can I store user input permanently in a file and later use that

Suppose I have new user and I want to store his name and pin and the money he deposit, how do I store it so that next time when the program run or the user comes back to check or take out the money and enters the pin or his name it can check using a if statement that the pin and name is correct and show him the details.

I am thinking that when the user enter his name as a variable we store it in a file but I don't know how to exactly do it and after that how can we then run if statement on it again to check the pin is correct or not.

```
print("***********WELCOME TO THE BANK OF LOSS**************")
def make_an_acc():
    print("by maing an account in our bank your sure to lose all you money\n")
    print("plss enter your name\n")
    newname = input("\n")
    print("plss enter an insecure 4 digit code that can be hacked by any one \n")
    newpin = int(input("\n"))
    print("pls enter the amount you want to loss i mean deposit\n")
    newamount = int(input("\n"))

 def datastore():
   def namelist:
   namefile = open("namelist","wb");
   namefile.write(newname)
   shi = namefile.read(); `
```

I know my code is not complete but this is what I wrote

Comment: Depending on your needs, you can read up on `pickle`, `json`, `csv`, or `sqlite` and then go from there.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the comments in the code...

```
print("***********WELCOME TO THE BANK OF LOSS**************")
def make_an_acc():
    print("by maing an account in our bank your sure to lose all you money\n")
    print("plss enter your name\n")
    newname = input("\n")
    print("plss enter an insecure 4 digit code that can be hacked by any one \n")
    newpin = int(input("\n"))
    print("pls enter the amount you want to loss i mean deposit\n")
    newamount = int(input("\n"))
    # return the values, so they can be used outside the function
    return [newname, newpin, newamount]

def datastore(newname):
   """ you hand this function a newname and it writes it to a file """
    namefile = open("namelist","wb");
    namefile.write(newname)
    # close file after reading or writing
    namefile.close()
    # do the reading elsewhere - to store data, you don't need it
    # so delete this for now: shi = namefile.read(); 

# you can now do this to get a list of three elements: 
# name, pin, balance:
customer_details = make_an_acc()

# customer name was the first element, so to store it in a file:
datastore(customer_details[0])
```

I didn't have time to make this shine but here's a quick 'n dirty re-write using dictionaries and json that'll allow you to make new customers, load existing, get customer details and typical things of that nature. Maybe it'll give you a little inspiration:

```
import json

customers_file = "customers.json"

customers_dict = {}

def load_customers(filename=customers_file):
    """ you hand this function a filename and it returns a dictionary of all customers """
    with open(filename, "r") as customers_json:
        return json.loads(customers_json.read())

def save_customers(customers_dict, filename=customers_file):
    """ you hand this function a dictionary and a filename to save the customers """
    with open(filename, "w") as customers_json:
        customers_json.write(json.dumps(customers_dict)) 

def add_customer():
    """ pretty much your existing code - just return a dictionary instead """
    print("by maing an account in our bank your sure to lose all you money\n")
    print("plss enter your name\n")
    newname = input("\n")
    print("plss enter an insecure 4 digit code that can be hacked by any one \n")
    newpin = int(input("\n"))
    print("pls enter the amount you want to loss i mean deposit\n")
    newamount = int(input("\n"))
    # return the values, so they can be used outside the function
    customer_dict = {"name":newname, "pin":newpin, "balance":newamount}
    return customer_dict

def get_customer_details(customers):
    import pprint
    customer_name = input("Get details for which customer?")
    pprint.pprint(customers[customer_name])

# load existing
customers_dict = load_customers()
# add new
new_customer = add_customer()
# add single customer to "master" dictionary
customers_dict[new_customer["name"]] = new_customer
# save all
save_customers(customers_dict)
# get customer details by name
get_customer_details(customers_dict)
```

Comment: can we make a separate function  for name pin and newamount

Comment: @MatrixJammr Yes, that's certainly possible but I think it would be better to change it in a different way so you don't have to write a new function per customer detail. I'll edit the answer soon.

Comment: @MatrixJammr Check the updated answer for another take on your script

Comment: @MatrixJammr Did you downvote? Care to elaborate? You want a single function per customer/account detail? :-/

Comment: i did not downvote  you awanswer is perfect i cant down vote cuz iam new  i dont even have 15 points of reputation iam sorry i think it some one else you  anwser is right and it helped me a lot thanks and really did not downvote you

Comment: No problem - glad it worked :) It's just annoying when people down-vote without giving an explanation because I never know if I'm missing something obvious or doing something stupid. We can all make mistakes and learn - if someone just cares to tell us what's wrong.

Comment: I downvoted you. Don't take it so personally. It's often said that SO is not a "code-writing service", and that appears to be exactly what you've done. I wouldn't care, but this is clearly a homework problem, and using a module like JSON is certainly not acceptable if that's not what their teacher wants and they can't explain it. If you can provide justification for why I'm wrong, I will remove the downvote.

Comment: @MANA624 Thanks for explaining :) It's not that I took it personal but I do worry that my code sucks and that I'm too noob to see it. I'm self-taught and don't study anything "numerical" so how would I know? SO is *my* professor! :P Anyway, you're right! Now that you mention it, it *does* look homework-ish, SO shouldn't be a code-writing service and the best justification I can give is that the json version will show OP a better approach to saving/loading small datasets than my previous answer did (it relied on list indices and seemed quite brittle). So keep the down-vote for now, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could save this in a list or dict and then use, pickle or cpickle(python 2x) for save in plain text

this is very easy to use and fast

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(obj, file[, protocol])
```

and then

```
pickle.load(file)
```

protocol could be 0 or 1

> If the protocol parameter is omitted, protocol 0 is used. If protocol is specified as a negative value or HIGHEST_PROTOCOL, the highest protocol version will be used.

see examples
https://pymotw.com/2/pickle/

and this is the official doc
https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html

Answer (score -1):

Basically you want some kind of persistence for your data.

Python has a bunch of modules to deal with it. Check: https://docs.python.org/2/library/persistence.html